# How to avoid pixel shifting for embossed tiling in Gimp

Tags: gimp, filter, tiles

I'm trying to create tiles with a cloud embossing.

I generated the tiling clouds with `filter > render > clouds`  , and then applied `filter > distort > emboss`.

But the modified clouds don’t repeat properly anymore, as you can see I have transparent pixel vertically and some shift horizontally.

**How can-I control this aspect of the emboss filter, or how can I get the same result without this pixel shift?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edge of the emboss filter is not wrapping around the edge of your tile.

To get around this, tile your image into a much larger image by repeating the image (eg 3x3 tiles), run the emboss on the whole thing, and then crop back to the one centre tile again (not an edge tile).

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer.  
Note: I use [this script](http://registry.gimp.org/node/20868) to export the right tile without cropping.